# AS3 - Sorting an array of nested arrays

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How would I go about sorting an array of nested arrays, based on the contents of one of the nested arrays elements?

```
var nestedArray1:Array = new Array(0,0,1);
var nestedArray2:Array = new Array(0,0,9);
var nestedArray3:Array = new Array(0,0,7);
var nestedArray4:Array = new Array(0,0,3);

var parentArray:Array = new Array(nestedArray1,nestedArray2,nestedArray3,nestedArray4);
```

I would like to end up with an array sorted using the nested arrays 3rd element.

So tracing sortedParentArray would give me:
0,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,7,0,0,9

which is nestedArray1, nestedArray4, nestedArray3, nestedArray2

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can access an array index in the same way as a property (`array[2]` is the same as `array["2"]`) you can use [sortOn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29).

```
parentArray.sortOn("2", Array.NUMERIC);
```

You can also use the other indices as second or third sort fields if don't want an unpredictable order for equal entries.

```
parentArray.sortOn(["2","1","0"], Array.NUMERIC);
```

Comment: Would give a +2 for this great and simple example, but there is no such button :(

Comment: That's giving me perfect results. Thanks for replying ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think kapep answer is a solid answer (+1), but just for explaination's sake here is whats going on.

So you have some arrays:

```
var nestedArray1:Array = new Array(0,0,1);
var nestedArray2:Array = new Array(0,0,9);
var nestedArray3:Array = new Array(0,0,7);
var nestedArray4:Array = new Array(0,0,3);
```

And then those arrays are put into another array:

```
var parentArray:Array = new Array(nestedArray1,nestedArray2,nestedArray3,nestedArray4);
```

So really your parent array looks something like this:

```
var parentArray:Array = [
    [0,0,1],
    [0,0,9],
    [0,0,7],
    [0,0,1]
];
```

So to really understand how sorting works in ActionScript, you have to kind of understand a little something about how flash treats functions. Functions in flash can be first-class objects, which means that you can use a function just like you would any other type of object, assign it to a variable, pass function to another function as an argument when invoking it, stuff like that.

So lets look at one first:

```
var sortOnThirdElement:Function = function(a:Array, b:Array):int {
    if(a[2] > b[2]) return 1;
    if(a[2] < b[2]) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am creating a function called `sortOnThirdElement`, it takes two arguments and will return `1` if the third element `a` is greater than third element `b`, or `-1` if `b` is greater than `a`, and if they are the same it will return `0`. So lets give it a little test run:

```
trace(sortOnThirdElement(nestedArray1, nestedArray2)) // -1
trace(sortOnThirdElement(nestedArray3, nestedArray3)) // 0
trace(sortOnThirdElement(nestedArray4, nestedArray1)) // 1
```

Looks good. We are invoking our little function, and it should tell us what order they should be in. But it doesn't actually sort our parent array. That's where `Array.sort()` comes in.

Calling `Array.sort()` with no arguments means that it will do some default sorting (basically simple case-insensitive string sorting), but there is another way to use `Array.sort()`. You can pass it a function that will perform the comparison you want; or in this case our `sortOnThirdElement` function.

```
parentArray.sort(sortOnThirdElement);
trace(parentArray);  // 0,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,7,0,0,9
// or really [[0,0,1],[0,0,3],[0,0,7],[0,0,9]]
```

Your sort function can be as complicated or as simple as you like. It basically loops through your array, calling your sort function as many times as it needs until your array is in the right order. It uses the return values (-1,0,1) to figure that out. Strongly typed `Vectors` also has this functionality.

If I wanted descending order I could simply say:

```
parentArray.sort(sortOnThirdElement, Array.DESCENDING);
```

So in kapep's answer, he suggesting using `sortOn`, which is sort of like a little helper for generating the sort function I wrote before (`sortOnThirdElement`). It's basically saying only compare a property called `"2"` on each item in this array and do the comparison numerically (`Array.NUMERIC`) rather than by string (the default, where `100` comes before `99`). More or less, it dynamically generates a comparison function based on the input you give it and then sorts using that.

But hopefully that explains a little more about how sorting works in ActionScript.