# using a sort compare function on hierarchical data

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, sortcomparefunction

I am attempting to use sortcomparefunction to ensure a specific data entry is the last object of its parent. However when using the sortcomparefunction the objects being passed in are always the root object. is there another way i could sort my data to ensure the object named "Upload" is always at the bottom. Just to clarify im trying to sort the data held in objects 1 2 and 3 fo4r example.  My data is structured as below

`rootObject -Object1-namedObject1
                    namedObject2
                    Upload
            Object2- stackObject
                     Upload
                     errorprofile

```
        Object3-images
                Upload
                Video`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418572/multidimentional-array-sort-in-as3 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008806/as3-sorting-an-array-of-nested-arrays

Comment: these are different problems to what is above