# Arranging array of nested objects by one of the nested variables - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular JS to provide output for an endpoint, the logic to achieve this output is created in the controller as follows:

```
myApp.controller('AnalyticsController',['$scope','$rootScope','$location','token_service','api_service',function($scope,$rootScope,$location,token_service,api_service){

  var analytics = api_service.get_analytics()
  analytics.then(function(response){
    $scope.analytics = response;
    $rootScope.spinner = false;
  })
}])
```

Please note: get_analytics is from another script and the data comes from that service.

The output I get is a nested object, in the console it looks like as follows:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
    Devices:Array[1]
    Id:"eefd439f-1e2e-481e-815d-0a2ce9a38bbe"
    KeyHolderDeviceConfiguration:null
    Name:"Shaun m "
    Photos:null
    Type:2
    __proto__:Object
1:Object
2:Object
```

There are more objects in the list but I figure there's no point opening them as is just repetition.

I wish to separate each nested object in the actual output, so there is one set of results for each 'Name'. Any idea how I would go about doing this?

I saw a similar problem - [AS3 - Sorting an array of nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008806/as3-sorting-an-array-of-nested-arrays) - but I am unsure how to apply this to my problem. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use .then the response contain more than property

you should assign data like this

```
$scope.analytics = response.data;
```

Comment: I've made that change and I still get the same output in the console, and I actually get no output now in the browser. Perhaps a sort function to abstract the nested object from the array? I'm unsure.

Comment: Can you put debugger; and post me the response object